# Multilingual MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, desktop, multilingual, messagebox

I have to make a multi-lingual desktop application in C# 3.5. I know how to add multilingual text for labels at design time.

But I am unable to find how to make Messagebox and Confirm dialogs multilingual? Do I have to add if/else conditions in code to check the selected language?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: I was up in Montreal working for MX for a few weeks some time ago.  The joy of windows is that the language wasn't as important as the layout.  The IDE was in French, but since the buttons didn't change position I was able to navigate just fine after a while.  Are you sure that something as trivial as message boxes really need to be bilingual?

Comment: If the whole App is bilingual, I think that yes, message boxes too must be.

Comment: @Steve H.: Well, try to ask that the Users from arabic countries (they usually have a right-to-left layout). Also, message boxes are meant to be read and understood (eventhough people rarly do either) so it's important the person understands the language the text is in and there are still people out there who don't speak english, eventhough you US folks usually fail to remember that the USA and UK together have less than 10% of worlds population.

Comment: you can always make your own beatiful MessageBox.

Comment: @dbemerlin: We may fail to remember that we make up less than 10% of the world population, but because we make up 23% of the global GDP, English remains the most common language learned as a second language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Resources. (Can be found at Project -> Properties... -> Resources tab)

If you use Resources tab then VisualStudio will create `Resources.resx` file in `Properties` folder for you where you can store different type of resources. (e.g. Images, Audio and Strings)
You can add any localizable strings there and use them later like `Properties.Resources.MyMessageBoxTitle`.

Later when you want to add a support for another language you can copy that `Resources.resx` file and rename it to something like `Resources.it-it.resx` (or `Resources.fr.resx`). Resource manager then will automatically load the string from a corresponding resource file. (based on `Thread.CurrentUICulture`)

Comment: I can create resource files at project level and form level as well. If I add these resource strings in form resource files then how do I access them?

Comment: @Haris, it is not recommended to use form's resources in this way, because they are usually autogenerated by the designer and they are only used in Form's `InitializeComponent` method. After that there is no idealogically good way of getting them. (Besides of creating your own instance of `ComponentResourceManager` of course.)
So please prefer project-level resources for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the caption and message strings into resources and then access them via the auto-generated properties on the `Properties.Resources` class for your assembly.

The main resource file for a project can be created by viewing the project properties and clicking the Resources tab. If you don't already have a Resources.resx for your project, there will be a link on that tab to create one. Once it is created, you can add project-scoped resources such as images and strings.

Answer (score 1):

In the designer, on the parent form or control, there is a property called `Localizable`, set it to true, then, you can change it's `Language` property and change labels/move controls around so that the layout fits for that localization.

Doing so will create resource files accordingly.